# Find $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) \delta(x)dx $ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\delta (x)dx$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

> Let $f(x) = \exp(-x^{2})$, calculate
> $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) \delta(x)dx $$
> and
> $$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)\delta (x)dx.$$

I know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \delta (x)dx = f(0)$, is it the same if we change the integration limits to $[-1, 1]$ seeing as $0$ is in that interval?

Comment: Well - what is the "value" of ${\delta(x)}$ if ${x\neq 0}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since$$\int_a^bg(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\chi_{[a,\,b]}(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g\chi_{(a,\,b]}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g\chi_{[a,\,b)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g\chi_{(a,\,b)}dx,$$the choice $g(x)=f(x)\delta(x)$ lets you evaluate $\int_a^bgdx$ as $f(0)$ provided $0\in(a,\,b)$, or $0$ provided $0\notin[a,\,b]$. If $0\in\{a,\,b\}$ the integral is undefined, since the result wouldn't be the same for all four choices of the indicator function.

Comment: Of course there is a little bit of a notational concern here. This is well-defined measure-theoretic wise, viewing the Dirac delta as a measure defined by $$\int_a^b f \,d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{[a,b]} f\, d\mu = f(0)$$ but when viewed as a tempered distribution, this isn't strictly defined since $f\chi_{[a,b]}$ need not be a tempered distribution in general. That said, simple limiting/heuristic arguments can then lead to similar logic as the measure-theoretic approach to extend the definition.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You're absolutely right. The fact that we're taking $f(x)=\exp(-x^2)$ [makes it all right, though](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform).

Comment: This is true, but even for such a choice of $f$, $f\chi_{[a,b]}$ isn't a tempered distribution. (I get picky about distribution theory since the devil is in the details and it gets abused a bit haha, though it's almost always fine abuse of notation.)

Comment: @J.G. I'm sorry, I don't see what's the difference between 0 ∈ (, ) and 0 ∈ {,}

Comment: @schrodingal $(a,\,b)=\{x|a<x<b\},\,\{a,\,b\}=\{x|x=a\lor x=b\}$.

Comment: @J.G. oh, thank you, I should've known that haha